# What is the name of the lambda notation that uses integer offsets to refer to implicit single arguments?

Tags: function, lambda, functional-programming, theory, lambda-calculus

Looks kind of like this (the example shows church numerals and the Y-combinator):

```
zero := λ.λ.0
one  := λ.0             -- or more verbosely: λ.λ.1 0
two  := λ.λ.1 (1 0)
three:= λ.λ.1 (1 (1 0))

add := λ.λ.λ.λ.3 1 (2 1 0)

Y := λ.(λ.1 (0 0)) (λ.1 (0 0))
```

What is the name of this type of notation? I seem to have forgotten.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: This isn't about "software development".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [De Bruijn index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) of the [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)